# show unfollowed users

Tags: mysql

I am wrong again on my query.
i am trying to display users from my site that am not following.

**dating_users**

user_id | username

**follow_unfollow**

id | following | follower

```
SELECT * 
FROM dating_users 
LEFT JOIN follow_unfollow ON follow_unfollow.following = dating_users.user_id 
WHERE dating_users.user_id != ? AND follow_unfollow.follower != ? 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 7
```

I just simply want it to shows users am not following only.

Comment: and what results get you right now? what values does the table follow_unfollow contains in follower column?

Comment: the following is the id of the user i want to follow. while the follower is the logged in user id

Comment: there is no row found in the databse for the follow_unfollow unless if followed. but its not displaying list of users i can follow. but when i do it like this follow_unfollow.follower = ? it shows me users am following

Comment: am new to php. so am totally wrong i know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should work

```
SELECT u.* FROM dating_users AS u
LEFT JOIN follow_unfollow AS f ON (
    f.following = u.user_id AND f.follower = 1 # user A
)
WHERE u.user_id != 1
AND f.id IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e05fb7/2